# scroll bar in mfc

Tags: mfc

how to add Scroll bar to a static text in MFC dialog box

Comment: I have solved the problem by using a RichEditControl instead of a static text.

Answer (score 0):

A static can't have a scroll bar. If you mean a read-only edit box, just turn it on in the resource editor.

Comment: Hi Roel thanks for your reply.....but i have a long text to display...but full text is not getting displayed due to size of the static text box........so how is it possible without a scroll bar.....plz help me out

Comment: I have solved the problem by using a RichEditControl instead of a static text

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to create a scroll bar with static text control.

First you should add dialog box one scorll bar and one static text control.

step1: Set scroll positon or set scroll range of scroll bar

step2:create a member variable of static text

step3:static text member variable assigend getscrollrange of scroll bar

using cstring to int ie.means cstring to convert int format.viceversa